# I need help search for letters at beginning and ending of a line in unix

Tags: unix, search

I am just starting out in UNIX and I have a txt file (words.txt) and there is one word per line and I need to search and find the words that start with 'com' and end with 'ter'.  But I cannot figure out what to do, I can find all the words starting with 'com' by using 'grep ^com words.txt' but I do not know how to find all the words that meet both conditions.  I tried 'grep '^com.*ter$' words.txt' but that did not do anything.  So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `cat -vet words.txt` show any unexpected `^M` characters at the end of the lines?

Comment: You can find "com..." with `grep '^com'`. Can you find "...ter" with `grep 'ter$'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

grep '^com.*ter$' words.txt

Comment: OP specifically mentions: `I tried 'grep '^com.*ter$' words.txt' but that did not do anything`

Comment: Its perfectly working for me.

^ --> This is for starting word
$ --> This is for end word

Or you can try grep -E '^com.*ter$' words.txt

Comment: that is probably because as others have commented, it is likely OP's file format is windows style line endings.. you can check it out yourself - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos